# Is "Be nice be respectful" policy implemented on main sites and not rooms?

Tags: discussion, chat, code-of-conduct, be-nice-policy

Based on my past experience, I feel "Be nice be respectful" policy or "Code of conduct" is not implemented in chat rooms as better as they are in main sites. Because they have their own rules maybe.

In other words, is it allowed to use unfriendly language intentionally (that would obviously make the subject (me) uncomfortable and humiliated) to 'correct' his repeated mistakes on chat rooms so next time he would remember the experience and won't make same mistakes?

Further, is it okay to do same in a different room where subject actually didn't commit those mistakes? Like I committed mistakes in room A, he would use unfriendly messages in room B in front of others where I am also active.

If yes, why would it not be against code of conduct? It mentions be nice and kind and respectful if I'm not wrong.

Or is it like there can be exceptions? Where you can use unfriendly messages?

And what should you do (apart from fixing my own mistakes and keep working to improve them) if such things happen with you repeatedly from same user? (Happened twice in my case with same user for same reasons).

Comment: Anything on the network is expected to follow [the Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).  If there *was* an issue you'd need to report it in chat so a moderator in context could deal with it.

Comment: @cigien they have mixed answers and confusing too.

Comment: @Makoto moderators ignored it. I flagged a message. Ignored/declined because it wasn't considered "serious".

Comment: Okay, this is going to get real subjective real fast.  Chat is more relaxed than the main sites, but rule breaking isn't acceptable.  However each chat has its own general vibe, and some things are more relaxed in some places.  Can you provide more context as to what you flagged in what chat that you felt wasn't adhering to the Code of Conduct?

Comment: @Makoto it's a complex issue where I had my own problems and the other user's reaction to that made me uncomfortable. I mean if code of conduct really works on chat rooms, they should have flagged my message instead making me uncomfortable by unfriendly messages. That's it.

Comment: Basically, I was blamed for my past behavior today. To justify my last two days, my past history was used as a proof. I had already acknowledged my past. Chats which was again subjective whether it was problematic or not.

Comment: In short, if similar thing would happen here in comments on main site, they would have been removed or at least flagged. But that doesn't work in chats. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: What room was it in?  We can look at logs and make a best guess at the situation.

Comment: @Makoto @ ColleenV The Bridge. But please don't mention me there. I was already humiliated and affected my mental health to make it even worse.

Comment: ...I'm not seeing that room come up anywhere.  Got a direct link?

Comment: @Vikas For future reference, if you need to escalate something in chat that wasn't handled correctly in your opinion, you should raise a mod flag on for the site's mod team (you could choose one of your own posts) and explain the situation. If that doesn't help, you can always use the contact form linked at the bottom of the page to get help if you're being made to feel unwelcome.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61737732#61737732

Comment: @ColleenV okay. But I wanted to understand what made me uncomfortable wasn't considered uncomfortable by mods. Of course I was treated like that because of maybe my off topic chats and repeated mistakes. But code of conduct should be followed in my opinion. Like I have said before, I wouldn't mind a suspension instead. Or a warning from moderators.

Comment: That is why I feel there is difference in chat and main site policies.

Comment: If you feel uncomfortable, that is all that matters. You don't have to justify your feelings to ask a moderator or staff to investigate the situation for you, and if you raise a flag or use the form, it can be done privately. The mod may not agree with you about what should be done after investigating, but you should not hesitate to raise the issue. Not every mod judges something perfectly, especially in chat when mods from other sites can handle flags.

Comment: Just because your recent flag got declined, doesn't mean the rules aren't enforced.

Comment: I have encountered unfriendly messages twice from same user this year. Each time I felt humiliated.

Comment: I have done mistakes in other rooms last year but they didn't post unfriendly messages to correct me. I was suspended which was far better and within code of conduct. And it was far more fair.

Comment: I have edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: Hi - Arqade mod here.  The post was closed before I could leave a response, but I think we are blowing this out of proportion a bit.  Was the commenter a tad rude? Maybe a bit.  I don't think their main goal was to try and humiliate you.  They are trying to steer you in what they thought was the correct direction of posting a question rather than asking in Chat.  I can't speak about your past chat history since I'm not informed, but I don't think you did anything wrong personally.  If it were me, I'd say *Oh well* and move on.  I'm sorry you felt mistreated.

Comment: That being said, I don't think the user should be reprimanded for their actions.  I don't think it is serious enough to warrant it.

Comment: @TimothyG. I have been going through bad time since last one year. So it made me feel even worse and I felt Stackexchange rules are unfair to me. Maybe because I am already going through bad time it hurt me even more.

Comment: I am sorry to hear.  We all go through rough times, and I wish you well.  Try not to let this get to you.  Like I said, I think we are blowing this out of proportion, and I would just move on.  I'm not sure what you may be going through in your personal life, but I am willing to bet that a minor dispute in an online chatroom probably doesn't trump it, so lets forget about it.  Take care!

Comment: Did you raise a flag through the flag icon button that has the tooltip "flag this message as spam, inappropriate, or offensive", the button labeled "flag as spam/offensive", or the one labeled "flag for moderator"? Only the one labeled "flag for moderator" actually goes only to moderators. It opens a new popup which allows you to type a short explanation of the issue. The responding moderator, who, on chat.SE, could be *any* moderator from *any* SE site, can then evaluate the issue and take action, but can't respond directly to you through the flag interface.

Comment: The other two flagging buttons (i.e the ones indicating spam/offensive) send the flag to every user in chat with > 10k reputation, but also including moderators. Those users can then confirm or invalidate the flag. If a *net* of 6 users, or a moderator, indicate that flag is valid, then the message is deleted and the user gets a 30 minute chat suspension. If more users (or one moderator) indicate the flag is "invalid" than indicate it's "valid", then the flag is dismissed. Such flags do *not* guarantee that the flag is even seen by an actual moderator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think [this is the comment in question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61746441#61746441).

> Not in general, just that specific person having a history of hijacking conversation and spending hours and hours and hours with obvious questions he should use SE's main function for (and frankly the damned search function, he is notoriously uninformed)... He asked the same question in SU chat a little earlier, and got ignored by everyone for this reason

I don't think you're gonna get a whole lot of attention from mods on this one.  It doesn't actively read like it's against the Code of Conduct.

Case in point, the user to this point was [actively engaging you to use the main site's functionality](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61740891#61740891) to accomplish your task of asking questions that were on-topic on a main site.

This final comment is likely a result of being exasperated from the demonstrated unwillingness to heed advice.

It *could've* been sugar-coated a bit, but I don't see anything here that:

- Attacks you as a human being
- Calls you outside of your name
- Insults your intelligence
- Is racially motivated
- Targets any gender identity of yours

This is just someone that wanted you to post the questions in the right place as opposed to chat.

If you feel uncomfortable, then it'd be best to step away from chat for a while and clear your head.  You don't have to engage somewhere that you feel uncomfortable to.

Comment: Okay. But this comment and a previous comment (just before this comment I flagged) both were based on my past problems. Basically what wasn't right was  justifying my present with my past history. I no longer ask questions hours and hours. Further I asked nothing in The Bridge that would fit on main site. So why would he bring old history and tell it to others and humiliate me? That is where I don't see respect and kindness. It isn't fair.

Comment: He has pointed two times that I should have posted on SE but they wouldn't fit on main site at all. This is why it didn't make sense.

Comment: If someone would talk like that here in comments, I'm sure moderators would look into it. But that doesn't happen in chats.

Comment: @Vikas:  If I put myself in the commentator's shoes, I'd probably find myself saying something similar.  It doesn't go out of the way to attack you specifically, but to call out the pattern of behavior that's occurring.

Comment: @Vikas:  Given that chat is more synchronous than main site comments (which *really* should only be used for clarifications on questions anyway), it's more likely that conversations that involve something you said or did a while back come up.  That's the nature of online chat.  Unless you can demonstrate that you're *not* exhibiting that same pattern from a time past, then you'll be reminded of it when it becomes a flash point. In this case, it became a flash point.

Comment: I don't say I didn't make mistake. I have already acknowledged and working on it. And just then someone would blame you it isn't nice. What would you do if someone repeats mistake? Suspension would be better.

Comment: So...would you rather have been kicked from the room?  Bear in mind that's not something a diamond mod would do unless you had some kind of major offense, that'd be something that room mods would do if they were so inclined.

Comment: sure. Kick is better. At least it doesn't involve respect and kindness at all. No unfriendly messages/gossips in front of others in a different room where I apparently didn't make any mistake.

Comment: It wouldn't make me mentally upset.

Comment: Yeah I can't speak to that.  That's how you're taking it right now in the heat of the moment.  I'm going to recommend that you cool off and take a break from chat altogether.  Being able to see why there is a disagreement first requires that the disagreeing parties chill out for a while.  In this case though, I *really* can't see anything for a diamond mod to want to bother with, as this dispute in chat should be handled by the chat mods instead.

Comment: "This is just someone that wanted you to post the questions in the right place as opposed to chat." This was also not fair. Why should someone ask me this in a different room? It would still be fair if I was told this in SU room. That is where I repeated mistakes apparently (what I posted was again a subjective question. Wouldn't fit easily on main site) . This is where I don't see code of conduct and kindness and mutual respect. It was unfair.

Comment: Also Code of conduct mentions respect and kindness right?

Comment: So doesn't it mean if someone would communicate like that, it would be against code of conduct? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: Sometimes though - its worth taking critique in the spirt its meant in.  Quite a few chatrooms, root access included discourage using it for quick questions, so to speak. If there's a pattern of, well behavior that annoys others, and is unaddressed over time, maybe you should consider what he's recommending too - doing a little research, rather than expecting answers to be given to you.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek of course. That is what I try to. But I posted nothing in The Bridge that I would be humiliated like that. He should have blamed me in SU. I would still argue the language they use if rules on main site and chat are same.

Comment: uh, he spent quite a lot of time pointing  you elsewhere, and that was a response to when he was asked why...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Cool. Then it was definitely unfriendly. And that is why I asked the question. I don't understand how he didn't break code of conduct?

Comment: The only answer would be, be nice or respectful and kind rules can be broken to correct someone like me (who is still trying to improve)? If yes, I got my answer.

Comment: @Vikas Please stop balking & denying & accept what people are telling you. (Your behaviour here is more of what the quoted comment described.)

Comment: @philipxy I never denied that. Never said I never accepted that. I had already acknowledged it and reduced that behavior significantly. Not everyone learns at same speed you accept them to.

Comment: @Vikas sounds like person was explaining to the other chatroom user why they suggested you take the question elsewhere, with a bit of exasperation because you weren't learning after being told something multiple times. It was not very rude, and it wasn't targeting you in any way. In short: the problem is that *you* are getting insulted rather than listening to advice, not that users are being rude or unfriendly. If you indeed wanted to learn, you would accept people's criticism/advice instead of getting angry.

Comment: @Esther I understand what you mean. I have significantly reduced the behavior he exaggerated based on my past. I took his suggestions when he first time gave me couple of months ago. After that I've repeated those mistakes significantly less. If I can't fix behavior as quick as everyone else does, you can call me unfit for StackExchange. But the truth is I'm trying to not repeat mistakes. Also this question was more about knowing the rules/code of conduct to be honest in chat rooms. That will help me understand things even better.  I hope you'll understand my point of view.

Comment: I have even "punished" myself by not participating in my favorite rooms. Just to learn it hard way.

Comment: @Vikas:  I'm noticing that you're still balking about this in my inbox.  Please take the advice that's been provided to you.  The pattern of self-victimizing and being frustrated with others for telling you that a pattern of behavior is undesirable and needs to stop is actively harming your ability to see and think objectively on the matter, and is causing more consternation than this is fundamentally worth.  Take a break altogether if you have to, but there's really no value in perpetuating the conversation about your perspective in my inbox.  We *know* where you're coming from by now.